# TOC and header versions of section titles (titlesec interferes with fancyhdr)

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr, titlesec

I am working on a long document with many chapters, using report class.

I would like to have three different versions of certain section titles (long for document, medium for TOC, and short for header). I am using package `fancyhdr`, so I followed instructions in a nice [FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-runheadtoobig) (also given in this question: [How to use short subsection title in header but not in table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94892/how-to-use-short-subsection-title-in-header-but-not-in-table-of-contents)).

```
\section[TOC_title]{Full_title\sectionmark{Header_title}}
\sectionmark{Header_title}
```

(I believe that the idea is that the inside-title `sectionmark` takes care of the page the section starts on, and the outside one deals with the subsequent pages.)

This all worked fine. However, because my doc is double-spaced, I also used `titlesec` to shrink down some whitespace around chapter and section titles.

Now I get the TOC_title header on the page the section starts on (wrong), and then the (correct) Header_title header on subsequent pages. Obviously I would like to fix this.

I suspect that `fancyhdr` is a bad idea long-term and I should switch to another header package, but I don't want to mess with the current document. I also don't want to let go of `titlesec` right now because it really has helped a lot with the doublespaced whitespace, and the issue I am having is minor in comparison.

Is there a way to fix this using `titlesec`? I have tried reading the [documentation](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/titleps.pdf) but I am getting very confused. I would be very grateful for someone who already knows this package to make a suggestion.

This question has been asked before in [How do I put a short title in the header but a long title in the toc (clashing of titlesec package with sectionmark)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131763/how-do-i-put-a-short-title-in-the-header-but-a-long-title-in-the-toc-clashing-o). But the only answer suggests KOMA-script; I suspect that this is some other family of packages that I am not going to learn right now.

Let me also add that my dissertation is due tomorrow, so I will not have time to put together a small working example today. I am interested in solving this issue both today and long-term, so I can come back and do this later if necessary. But in the meantime, I would appreciate any answers today very much!

UPDATE (May 1, 2015): Here's a minimal working example. The Ponysec header on its first page is correct if \usepackage{titlesec} is commented out and not otherwise. The Carouselsec header uses Ulrike Fischer's minihack and works either way.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\funnysection}[3]
     {\let\orisectionmark\sectionmark
     \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}%
     \section[{#2}]{{#1}\orisectionmark{{#3}}}
     \orisectionmark{{#3}}
     \let\sectionmark\orisectionmark}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT    %%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Mychapter}
\section{Cactussec (UNIVERSION)}
No header on this page.
\clearpage
\section[Ponysec (TOC)]{Ponysec (main)\sectionmark{Ponysec (header)}}
\sectionmark{Ponysec (header)} 
Desired header here is "Ponysec (header)".
\clearpage
Desired header here is "Ponysec (header)".
\clearpage
\funnysection{Carouselsec (main)}{Carouselsec (TOC)}{Carouselsec (header)}
Desired header here is "Carouselsec (header)".
\clearpage
Desired header here is "Carouselsec (header)".
\end{document}
```

If the right solution (for me, who doesn't really know what KOMA/KONA/script means and yet wants to create decent typeset documents today, this week, this month despite this massive ignorance) is to use `titleps` instead of `fancyhdr`, I would still love to find out how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A minimal example showing the problem would help us to help you.

Comment: It's not really minimal, but there's an example in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131763/how-do-i-put-a-short-title-in-the-header-but-a-long-title-in-the-toc-clashing-o?. User wasarga was having the exact same problem. I can add a more compact example tomorrow.

Comment: KOMA-script a versatile bundle of classes and packages for LaTeX2e.

Comment: Well, this question hasn't really received enough attention, but it also has zero net upvotes, so rather than starting a bounty, I will accept @ulrikefischer's solid and increasingly appealing answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this to fool titlesec:

```
\let\orisectionmark\sectionmark
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}%
\section[TOCtitle]{Fulltitle\orisectionmark{Headertitle}}
\orisectionmark{Headertitle}
\let\sectionmark\orisectionmark
```

## EDIT

Some Remarks regarding the comments: You didn't provide a minimal example so most of it was guessing. titlesec calls internally `\sectionmark{TOCtitle}` so early that your own `\sectionmark` commands are too late. So I'm redefining `\sectionmark` to nothing so that titlesec can no longer set a mark and use a copy `\orisectionmark` to set your marks. Replacing the middle `\orisectionmark`'s  with `\sectionmark` should *not* work -- after all the command is defined to do nothing.

I don't know why you don't want to use the KONA-classes but imho a solution with titlesec would involve to drop fancyhdr and to use titleps instead. I'm quite sure that Javier implemented somewhere a way to set the marks correctly but as you already found out his documentations are not easy to read and finding something that works often involves a lot of trial and error and reading the code.

Comment: It works. This is a really great solution for tonight. But I put it directly around the sectionheader -- is that the only way it will work? I also can't quite parse what's happening, however. Is \orisectionmark a preexisting command? or is it just a placeholder saving sectionmark while you muss around with it? -- cont'd

Comment: cont'd -- and if so, did you mean 
\let\orisectionmark\sectionmark
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}%
\section[TOCtitle]{Fulltitle\sectionmark{Headertitle}}
\sectionmark{Headertitle}
\let\sectionmark\orisectionmark
(that is, the 2 "orisectionmark"s right after the section declaration should actually be "sectionmark"s) -- because that's actually what worked for me.

Comment: And of course I would love a better solution for the future (i.e., not involving KOMA-script). Does titlesec, which seems like such a thought-out package, really not provide for this triple tier of section titles?

Comment: I registered so I could upvote your answer (why do I need such a crazy secure password for this site of all sites???), which is why my name changed.

Answer (score 2):

Using KOMA-script, there would be no problem :-)

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[tocentry={platypus dancing till morning},%
head={dancing platypus}]%
{The platypus went on dancing till the mornig sun rose
over the hills}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: annaTocHeadTitles]

Comment: Are you being cruel only to be kind?...

Comment: To be honest, i haven't read the complete question. There is a whole bunch of packages out there, extending the standard classes with this and that. And there are `memoir` and `KOMA` provinding many of these things just *out of the box*.